# TFS Environment move to Different Server in the same domain

Tags: tfs

We have TFS server to be moved to a new Hardware please suggest the steps involved and the best approach.

The DB instance will also change will just Backing up and Restoring the Collection DBs be fine? and attaching these collections to the New TFS setup?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: There's a lot of documentation on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance). This question is quite broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.
The answer to both your questions is "It depends..." ;)

Comment: Do you also need to upgrade TFS version or just use the same version?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT we just need to change the hardware of the existing environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as *DaveShaw* suggested in the comment, there are official tutorials in MSDN, you could simply follow the suggestion there.  The steps are very clear and detail

**[Restore data to a different server than the current one for TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance)**

If you also want to do the version upgrade something you could pay attention such as :

**Pre-production upgrade** is just a **dry run** of your upgrade in a production environment.

Usually  we use this to test your upgrade. This process test upgrades the databases. You can use this to simultaneously test your TFS on another hardware while continue to use your existing older TFS up.

Once you are ready for upgrade, **restore the databases again** and just use the **Production Upgrade**  scenario during the server configuration wizard.

Besides, suggest you directly move the changes in the production environment later, a [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/19/in-place-upgrade-to-tfs-2017-rtw-release-to-web-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/) for In-place upgrade to  for your reference.